# Pycharm: why I can't import cabocha library

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

My os is Mac OS, and I have install successfully conda, and cabocha.
and I can import cabocha.analyze (which is a Yet Another Japanese Dependency Structure Analyzer - GitHub Pages ) successfully in terminal.

```
(wmm_env) A1706-084:wmm_env k.den$ python
Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan 16 2018, 12:04:33) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from cabocha.analyzer import CaboChaAnalyzer
>>>
```

But in the pycharm, there is error:

```
    from cabocha.analyzer import CaboChaAnalyzer
     ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cabocha'
```

Comment: Do you use the same virtualenv in Pycharm as in your command line?

Comment: hi thanks! I have used the virtualenv in the pycharm, but there may be some issue when I added the virtualenv in the pycharm, could you tell me how to add the virtualenv in Pycharm  in detail.

Comment: hi @Adonis,  do pycharm version(professional and community ) cause this issue? my pycharm is  community.

Comment: Both versions of PyCharm  should handle an additional package. By the way, have you tried installing other packages to see if you have the same issue? The relevant doc: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html.html

Comment: Hi, other package is ok such as mecab